# Handling common files in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a project that relies heavily on database credentials, and it is convenient to put them in one location, but I have numerous subfolders that need to `import` that file. From a lot of searching, it seems like there are many (suboptimal/overly complicated) ways to do this, but I'm wondering what is the simplest way to include one file across many directories.

```
project/
    credentials.py
    task1/
       fileA.py
    task2/
       fileB.py
```

where `credentials.py` looks like this:

```
database = "my_database"
database_user = "me"
database_password = "password"
```

What's the best way to `import` the contents of `credentials.py` in `fileA.py` and `fileB.py`? Is there a completely different and better way to structure this project?

EDIT: Is there a way to accomplish this so that it does not matter which directory I run each task from?

Comment: Have you checked out packages? https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages

Comment: Indeed I have. I've tried to solve the problem by basically creating a ````credentials```` module, but I could not get it to work properly.

Comment: Maybe posting a question on why you couldn't get it to work properly would be more beneficial for you

Comment: I think you're trying to say that I should think of ````project```` as a package, and each task and the credentials as modules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just happened to have the same issue today.  You can insert the following in fileA.py and fileB.py:

```
import sys, os
# prepend parent directory to path
sys.path = [os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), os.pardir)] + sys.path
import credentials
```

Comment: Oops, typing in a hurry. Thanks, I corrected it now.

Answer (score 1):

You could just add `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/path/to/directory/with/credentials` to your `~/.bashrc`, reopen your shell and then just use `import credentials`.

This is assuming your on a UNIX based system.

For windows the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/using/windows.html) says you can add `set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;C:\My_python_lib` to your `autoexec.bat` file. `msconfig` is a graphical interface to this file.

Comment: While this works, I feel like it is quite complicated when working in a multi-developer environment.